# Google Checkout - Redirect Page parameter in XML API?

Tags: xml, google-checkout

The PayPal API has what's commonly referred to as a "Thank You page" -- basically a redirect page, after the user's gone through the Google Checkout process. What is the equivalent parameter to pass this value to via Google Checkout's XML API?

(I notice that their [integration flow ends after redirecting the user to the Google checkout page](http://code.google.com/apis/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_XML_API.html#create_checkout_cart). Is such not possible?)

-- Update

It looks like adding the following to the initial XML send puts a small link "[Return to [Merchant Name]](http://redirecturl.example.com)" on the final order page - is there a way to change [Merchant Name], and or, having the page redirect (rather than just link) back to the a custom thank you page?

```
  <checkout-flow-support>
    <merchant-checkout-flow-support>
      <continue-shopping-url>
      http://redirecturl.example.com
  </continue-shopping-url>
    </merchant-checkout-flow-support>
  </checkout-flow-support>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like adding the following to the initial XML send puts a small link "[Return to [Merchant Name]](http://redirecturl.example.com)" on the final order page - is there a way to change [Merchant Name], and or, having the page redirect (rather than just link) back to the a custom thank you page?

```
  <checkout-flow-support>
    <merchant-checkout-flow-support>
      <continue-shopping-url>
      http://redirecturl.example.com
  </continue-shopping-url>
    </merchant-checkout-flow-support>
  </checkout-flow-support>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no automatic re-direct for the buyer after the Google Checkout transaction finishes.

You can provide a link that the user **has** to click in order get back to your site after completing the order.

See the continue_url paramenter:

http://code.google.com/apis/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_HTML_API_Parameter_Reference.html#tag_continue-shopping-url